# OOM Error but no Image (Just Strings) - Intent from Activity 1 to 2 to 3

Tags: java, android, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database, out-of-memory

**UPDATE: If I go to the AddEmployeeActivity from my MainActivity it is just fine, but if I go to it from my BusinessActivity it crashes.**

Update: I've also commented out any code that could be related to images and it still crashes.

All of the SO articles I have looked up seem to mention images/bitmaps, but I am only sending Strings/text. I have tried sending the model object itself, and even just a single string and I still get the OOM error.

***GOAL:*** I am trying to send information(Strings) from Activity 1 to Activity 2 to Activity 3. I am able to successfully send it from Activity 1 to Activity 2, but when I try to forward that same info to Activity 3 it crashes with the following and I am not sure why:

```
    E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock/com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.AddEmployeeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:446)
                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2544)
                         at com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.AddEmployeeActivity.onCreate(AddEmployeeActivity.java:80)
                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                      Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12086796 byte allocation with 8124080 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1179)
                         at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:770)
E/UncaughtException:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1727)
                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:945)
                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
                         at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
                            ... 31 more
D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, timestamp=1519160170072, fatal=1}]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock, PID: 30983
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock/com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.AddEmployeeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:446)
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2544)
                      at com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.AddEmployeeActivity.onCreate(AddEmployeeActivity.java:80)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12086796 byte allocation with 8124080 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1179)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:770)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1727)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:945)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
                        ... 31 more
```

It points to this line of the third activity (AddEmployeeActivity.java):

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_addemployees);
```

---

*Activity 1 (which uses MyAdapterBusiness.java) is sending a model object(Businesses) from a RecyclerView:*

```
  public class MyAdapterBusiness extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterBusiness.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Businesses> mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;




public MyAdapterBusiness(Context context){
    mContext = context;

}
//Other Methods

    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Businesses business = mDataSet.get(position);

    holder.bizNameTV.setText(business.getbusinessName());
    holder.bizCityTV.setText(business.getbusinessCity());


    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3887aa"));
            holder.bizNameTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.bizCityTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


            BusinessActivity.display(mContext, business);
        }
    });

}
```

**Note that I am using the "display" method to send from Activity 1 to Activity 2. Here is the method:**

```
 public static void display(Context context, Businesses businesses) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, BusinessActivity.class);
    mBusinesses = businesses;
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

---

*In my onClick from Activity 2 to Activity 3 I try to run same/similar method:*

```
addEmployeeTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            String companyID = mBusinesses.getbusinescompanyID();
            AddEmployeeActivity.display(BusinessActivity.this, companyID);

        }
    });
```

*In Activity 3 the method looks like:*

```
   public static void display(Context context, String companyID) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AddEmployeeActivity.class);
    //mBusinesses = businesses;
    companyId = companyID;
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

---

Activity 2 (BusinessActivity.java):

```
public class BusinessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/*private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private String mActivityTitle;*/

//private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
//private CharSequence mTitle;

//DRAWER/Menu Stuff
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;
ImageView menu, closeDrawer;
//RelativeLayout navHeader;
View navHeader;

//Profile Stuff
DatabaseReference employeesRefPhoto, employeesRefFname, employeesRefLname;
FirebaseDatabase database;
String photoUrl;
ImageView profilePhoto;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String currentUserString;
TextView nameTV, businessName, businessCity;

ImageView home, editBusiness;
TextView employeesTV, currentDate, addEmployeeTV;
static Businesses mBusinesses;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business);

    Log.i("mBusinesses", mBusinesses.toString());
    Log.i("mBus City", mBusinesses.getbusinessCity().toString());
    Log.i("mBiz NAME", mBusinesses.getbusinessName().toString());

    /////////////////////////
    //METHODS
    setupDrawerLayout();
    initViews();
    onClickMethods();
    //////////////////////////

    currentDate.setText(MethodHelper.getDate()); //SET DATE


    // menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });



    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    currentUserString = currentUser.getUid().toString();



    closeDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //INFORMATION FOR MENU/////////////////////
    //PROFILE PHOTO
    //currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //currentUserString = currentUser.getUid().toString();

    //setupDrawerLayout();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    employeesRefPhoto = database.getReference("Employees").child(currentUserString).child("photoDownloadUrl");
    employeesRefPhoto.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i("onDataChange","Inside");

            try {
                photoUrl = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                Log.i("photoUrl", photoUrl);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photoUrl).into(profilePhoto);
                profilePhoto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.i("Null", e.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Cancelled",databaseError.toString());
        }
    });

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    //GET BUSINESS//////////////////////////////////

    //FIRST NAME
   employeesRefFname = database.getReference("Employees").child(currentUserString).child("firstName");
    employeesRefFname.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                Log.i("biz name", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                nameTV.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {  Log.i("FNull?", e.toString());     }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {   Log.d("Cancelled",databaseError.toString());     }
    });





} //END OF ONCREATE

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//INITIALIZE VIEWS
private void initViews(){
    navHeader= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    //PROFILE NAME
    nameTV = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.employeeFname);
    menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    closeDrawer = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.closedrawer);
    profilePhoto = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.profilephoto);

    //HEADER
    menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
    editBusiness = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.editbusiness);

    businessName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.individualbizname);
    businessCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.individualbizcity);

    currentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentDate);

    employeesTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeesText);
    addEmployeeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addemployee);

}

//INTENTS FOR THE FOOTER OF THE SCREEN
private void onClickMethods() {

    //HEADER /////////////////////

    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(BusinessActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        }
    });

    ///HEADER 2
    String businessCityString = mBusinesses.getbusinessCity().toString();
    businessCity.setText(businessCityString);
    businessName.setText(mBusinesses.getbusinessName().toString());


    //FOOTER ////////////////////




    addEmployeeTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            String companyID = mBusinesses.getbusinescompanyID();
            AddEmployeeActivity.display(BusinessActivity.this, companyID);

        }
    });
}

//MENU / DRAWER
//https://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/
private void setupDrawerLayout() {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            //If Clicked...then get item and go to associated page
            switch(menuItem.getTitle().toString())
            {
                case "Profile":
                    Log.i("Profile", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                    startActivity(new Intent(BusinessActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    break;


                case "Logout":
                    Log.i("Logout", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(BusinessActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    break;
                //startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }

            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static void display(Context context, Businesses businesses) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, BusinessActivity.class);
    mBusinesses = businesses;
    context.startActivity(i);
}


} //END OF CLASS
```

---

Activity 3 (AddEmployeeActivity.java) starts out as:

```
public class AddEmployeeActivity extends Activity {

//VARIABLES


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_addemployees);
```

activity_register_addemployees.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@color/redButton"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.75">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:src="@drawable/backarrow" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/registrationImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/addemployeesresize" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:tint="@color/red"
                android:src="@drawable/user"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstNameET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.55"
                android:hint="@string/firstName"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/user"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastNameET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.55"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/lastName"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/phone"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNumberET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.55"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/phoneNumber"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/email"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.55"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/emailAddress"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lock"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ssnET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.55"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/ssn"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blueText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkmarkImage"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/checkmark" />


    </RelativeLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You will have better luck if you post the complete Java stack trace, not just the one line.

Comment: It is obvious that something is wrong with this xml file: `activity_register_addemployees` post your xml

Comment: Posted full stack trace and xml

Comment: Also, I have used this activity before and it has worked just fine (activity_register_addemployees). Nothing was changed in the XML... only in the Java..

Comment: More Testing: If I go to the AddEmployee activity from any other screen its fine. Also if I get rid of my display method and do a regular intent to simply go to the activity without sending any data it STILL crashes with OOM